# Guardar datos en MySQL utilizando JavaFX

Tags: mysql, javafx

Necesito insertar datos en `mysql` en una tabla de clientes, utilizando una interfaz grafica con `JFX`.

El problema es que no puede acceder a capturar los datos de dicho formulario en mi clase de conexion.

```
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXComboBox?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXDatePicker?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="entrevinos_login.FormUserSignUpController">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="btnregistrar" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="9.0" prefHeight="523.0" prefWidth="910.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <Pane layoutX="-12.0" layoutY="-10.0" prefHeight="524.0" prefWidth="132.0" style="-fx-background-color: #311019;" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="-12.0" />
            <Label layoutX="195.0" layoutY="35.0" text="Registro de Usuarios" textFill="#ab1c44">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="25.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <JFXTextField fx:id="CédulaInput" focusColor="#ab1c44" labelFloat="true" layoutX="195.0" layoutY="110.0" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="247.0" promptText="Cédula de Identidad" />
            <JFXTextField fx:id="EmailInput" focusColor="#ab1c44" labelFloat="true" layoutX="533.0" layoutY="110.0" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="270.0" promptText="Email" />
            <JFXTextField fx:id="NombreInput" focusColor="#ab1c44" labelFloat="true" layoutX="195.0" layoutY="173.0" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="247.0" promptText="Nombre" />
            <JFXTextField fx:id="Apellido" focusColor="#ab1c44" labelFloat="true" layoutX="533.0" layoutY="173.0" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="270.0" promptText="Primer Apellido" />
            <JFXDatePicker fx:id="FechaInput" defaultColor="#ab1c44" layoutX="195.0" layoutY="243.0" overLay="true" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="247.0" promptText="Fecha de Nacimiento" />
            <JFXTextField fx:id="TeléfonoInput" focusColor="#ab1c44" labelFloat="true" layoutX="533.0" layoutY="243.0" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="270.0" promptText="Teléfono" />
            <JFXComboBox fx:id="PaisInput" focusColor="#ab1c44" labelFloat="true" layoutX="195.0" layoutY="316.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="247.0" promptText="País" />
            <JFXComboBox fx:id="ProvinciaInput" focusColor="#ab1c44" labelFloat="true" layoutX="533.0" layoutY="316.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="132.0" promptText="Provincia" />
            <JFXComboBox fx:id="CantónInput" focusColor="#ab1c44" labelFloat="true" layoutX="672.0" layoutY="316.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="132.0" promptText="Cantón" />
            <JFXButton layoutX="208.0" layoutY="413.0" text="Borrar todo" />
            <JFXButton layoutX="640.0" layoutY="413.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="164.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ab1c44;" text="Continuar" textFill="WHITE" />
            <Separator layoutX="187.0" layoutY="78.0" prefHeight="12.0" prefWidth="625.0" />
            <Label layoutX="868.0" layoutY="-4.0" text="X" textFill="#ab1c44">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="25.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <ImageView fitHeight="36.0" fitWidth="43.0" layoutX="136.0" layoutY="35.0" onMouseClicked="#GoBackToLogin" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@images/icons8_Back_To_100px.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Acceso a base de datos:**

```
package entrevinos_login;

import database.Database;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class FormUserSignUpController implements Initializable {
    Connection con;
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        try {
            createConnection();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FormUserSignUpController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } 

    void createConnection() throws SQLException {
        try{
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/entrevinos","root","mysql");
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void btnContinuar(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        try{
            String name = .getText();
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String dbop = "INSERT INTO CLIENTES VALUES('"+ nombre +"')";
            stmt.execute(dbop);
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }


     @FXML
    private void GoBackToLogin(MouseEvent event) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("x");
        Parent home_page_parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        Scene home_page_scene = new Scene (home_page_parent);
        Stage app_stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        app_stage.hide();
        app_stage.setScene(home_page_scene);
        app_stage.show();
    }   
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar en la pregunta cuál es el error? De lo contrario, si alguien quisiera ayudarte tendría que leer todo tu código, comprender su lógica y tratar de ver dónde está el error. Indicando el error agilizarás una respuesta más efectiva.